# Accessing .Net enums in Iron python

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython

I'm trying to access .Net(C#) enums in [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/), lets say we have

**Test.dll**

```
// Contains Several Enums
enum TestType{..}
enum TestQuality{..}
....
....
enum TestStatus{..}

//Similarly Multiple functions
public void StartTest(TestType testType, TestQuality testQuality){..}
....
....
public TestStatus GetTestStatus(){..}
```

and now if I try to call the above functions, I need to choose the appropriate enum parameters and so far what I did is this,

**Iron Python [vs2012]**

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('Test.dll')
from TestDll import *

test = Test()
# Initiate Enums
enumTestType = TestType
enumTestQuality = TestQuality
....
....
enumTestStatus = TestStatus

#Call Functions
test.StartTest(enumTestType.Basic, enumTestQuality.High)
....
....
# goes on
```

now the above IronPython code works fine, the only odd bit here is that I need to initiate all the enums(Intellisence doesnt work here) before I use them with the functions, this will become more difficult when there are more enums to use. whereas in C# environment(vs2012) we dont have to initiate but we can use them straight away when calling functions.

Is there a better way of dealing this in IronPython?

Please correct me if I'm wrong, thanks!

Comment: I know that you must import & instantiate all the enums that you're using. As long as you import all, everything looks fine for me. I don't know any workaround for this.

Comment: Importing & Intantiating .net class is fine but why it's members(enums)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the enums are contained within your `Test` class you can either use them fully qualified

```py
test.StartTest(Test.TestType.Basic, Test.TestQuality.High)
```

or by importing

```
from TestDll.Test import TestQuality, TestType
test.StartTest(TestType.Basic, TestQuality.High)
```

If the enums are in the same namespace as the `Test` class they should be usable without additional imports:

```
test.StartTest(TestType.Basic, TestQuality.High)
```

Comment: Thanks again Simon, Great.! I thought this `from TestDll import *` would fix but didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I fixed it in another way: using `ScriptRuntime.LoadAssembly`.

Prerequisites:

- VS2013
- C# app executable, plus the Test.dll assembly. IronPython is hosted by the C# app.
- **Test.dll**: (note that **all** is within the TestDll namespace)

  ```
  namespace TestDll
  {
      // Contains Several Enums
      enum TestType{..}
      enum TestQuality{..}
      ....
      ....
      enum TestStatus{..}

      //Similarly Multiple functions
      public void StartTest(TestType testType, TestQuality testQuality){..}
      ....
      ....
      public TestStatus GetTestStatus(){..}
  }
  ```

I simply created the IronPython engine this way:

```
eng = Python.CreateEngine();
eng.Runtime.LoadAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(TestType)));   // This allows "from TestDLL import *" in Python scripts
```

and then, execute the script with the usual

```
string pysrc = ...; // omitted, taken from the python script below
ScriptSource source = eng.CreateScriptSourceFromString(pysrc);
ScriptScope scope = eng.CreateScope();
source.Execute(scope);
```

This allowed me to write this Python code and execute it within the C# app: (note that I'm using the enum names directly)

```
from TestDll import *

test = Test()

#Call Functions
test.StartTest(TestType.Basic, TestQuality.High)
....
....
# goes on
```